# Gruntjs - Watch/Browsersync doesn't reload php

Tags: gruntjs, browser-sync, grunt-contrib-watch

So I am using grunt to help me develop sites.
For last two weeks I am having issues with Browsersync/Watch.

When I am making changes to a php files, browsersync doesn't detect any changes. Even, when I am reloading the site manually, source code is not updated. Most funny part is, this code gets updated after "some time" or when I am restarting grunt.

```
watch: {
    php: {
        files: ['*.php', '**/*.php'],
    }
},
// Run Browser Sync
browserSync: {
    default_options: {
        bsFiles: {
            src: [
                "**/*.php",
                "*.php",
            ]
        },
        options: {
            watchTask: true,
            proxy: 'g.test',
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone had familiar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a

```
 body
```

tag in your PHP files? 
Also, when running grunt, do you have a script (like one below) injected under body?

```
<script id="__bs_script__">
//<![CDATA[document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.7'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I have body tag and this script is also there

Comment: Ok, I see. Last question. Are you using MAMP/WAMP or other local servers?

Comment: I am using MAMP PRO on MacOS

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's wrong. If you have a cache module in PHP on, turn it off and see if it works.